# How to properly delete an instance of a model in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to delete an instance of an event from my calendar. I then want Django to redirect to the calendar page upon deletion of the event.

In my views.py, I have defined an event_delete function:

```
def event_delete(request, event_id=None):
    Event.objects.get(pk=event_id).delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cal:calendar"))
```

In my urls.py I have defined a url for deletion:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = "cal"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^index/$", views.index, name="index"),
    url(r"^calendar/$", views.CalendarView.as_view(), name="calendar"),
    url(r"^event/new/$", views.event, name="event_new"),
    url(r"^event/edit/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$", views.event, name="event_edit"),
    url(r"^event/delete/$", views.event_delete, name="event_delete"),
]
```

and in my event.html, I have defined an a tag that takes in event_delete:

```
<a class="btn cancel-button buttons login_btn" href="{% url 'cal:event_delete' %}" value="Delete" style="font-family:Optima;">Delete Event</a>
```

When I try to delete an event, it redirects me back to the calendar page but I still see the event. If I try again, it gives me the error

```
DoesNotExist at /event/delete/
Event matching query does not exist.
```

When I check in my admin however, I still see the instance of the event. Please advice as to how I can resolve this.

Edit: This is what my event.html looks like:

```
{% extends 'cal/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Event
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


<!--<div class="clearfix">
  <a class="btn btn-info left" href="{% url 'cal:calendar' %}"> Calendar </a>
</div>-->
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{ field.label }} <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ field.label }} <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="user_card">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h3 id="form-title">Add Event</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">
        <form method="POST" action="">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            {{ form.title }}
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3 description">
            {{ form.description }}
          </div>
          <div class="start_and_end_time">
            <span class="timelabel">Start</span>
            {{ form.start_time }}
            <span class="spacer"></span>
            <span class="timelabel">End</span>
            {{ form.end_time }}
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
            <a class="btn cancel-button buttons login_btn" href="{% url 'cal:calendar' %}" value="Cancel" style="font-family:Optima;">Cancel</a>
            <a class="btn cancel-button buttons login_btn" href="{% url 'cal:event_delete' form.id%}" value="Delete" style="font-family:Optima;">Delete Event</a>
            <span class="spacer"></span>
            <input class="btn buttons add-button login_btn" type="submit" value="Add Event" style="font-family:Optima;">
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: your urlpatterns don't accept an id in event_delete and your template doesn't provide one. You  need to pass the id similar to event_edit. You should also be using a post method for that, but one step at a time. See doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 2):

```
href="{% url 'cal:event_delete' %}"
```

Here, you are not providing the id of the event to delete, so it cannot work. Change to the following:

```
href="{% url 'cal:event_delete' form.instance %}"
```

The second problem is in your *urls.py*, where the delete URL should be fed with an ID in order to know what to delete. Just follow a pattern similar to the *edit* URL:

```
    url(r"^event/delete/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$", views.event_delete, name="event_delete"),
```

Comment: I have updated my question to include my event.html. I guess since I am taking in the form, would I do form.id or form.instance.id? But even when I try that, I am now getting this error:

NoReverseMatch at /event/new/
Reverse for 'event_delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['event/delete/$']

Comment: @SatyenSingh Answer edited. There is also a problem in your _urls.py_ that I did not see at first.

Comment: thank you for your help! So this helped me delete the event once but then when I tried to create a new event, it said the reversematch for event/new/ is incorrect

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /event/new/
Reverse for 'event_delete' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['event/delete/(?P<event_id>\\d+)/$']

Comment: i know what you said works though because when I did delete the event that was already created, it actually got deleted, i checked in my admin, its just that new error that I cannot figure out...